# BCP failing to upload CSV file ("Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file" )

Tags: sql-server, csv, t-sql, sqlcmd, bcp

I'm trying to automate the copying of some of the columns of a table in one database to a table on another server with my limited skill set.

Approach I've been attempting:

1. Using SQLCMD to run a simple SQL query and save a 700 row CSV file containing the data (with headers, presently).
2. Use BCP to upload that CSV file onto the other server

Each step above is saved in two .BAT files. These will be run nightly using Task Scheduler.

Step 1 is working insofar as I can execute the command and I get a CSV with the data 'looking' exactly as I want
Step 2 (BCP) is failing whatever I try.

Here's the SQLCMD command for step 1:

```
sqlcmd -S server -i "sqlqueryfile.sql" -o "filepath.csv" -W -w 999 -s"," -h -1
```

Here's the BCP command for step 2:

```
bcp desttable in "filepath.csv" -S server -d database -T -q -t "," -f formatfile.fmt
```

Here's the error message I'm getting:

```
Starting copy...
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file
0 rows copied.
```

So, am I doing something wrong in the way I'm generating the CSV file, perhaps? Or should I not be including headers in that file? Or am is it a BCP parameter abuse error?

Or can you not tell from this information? I've not changed the .FMT table since generating it - could it be an issue with that?

I've not got a lot of experience with doing this but I HAVE succeeded in doing this another time, for another query/table. I cannot see the difference between what I was doing then and what I am doing now, frustratingly.

If someone has a suggestion for a better way of doing this from scratch then that would also be appreciated, but in the mean time it would be great to find out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you not just use linked servers for this?

Comment: That would be my preferred solution and what I used to do, yes - but there is an ongoing issue which means this is not longer possible. Also I'm trying to create a one-stop shop environment for analytics, but that is secondary.

Comment: Presumably using openquery() is also ruled out for the same reasons. I don't think this is answerable without seeing the content of the file and debugging it by divide&conquer.

Comment: Indeed. I had to use OpenQuery for the linked server approach before anyway due to the geography format of some of the columns.

So will a view of some of the CSV file be useful? I can probably add a sample of it here, plus I can add the FMT file contents as there is nothing sensitive there.

Comment: you could try. Have you checked you have the correct row terminator in the format file for the last column. Presumably you've already been through the debugging steps of starting with exporting a single column and single row?

Comment: I think your first mistake is assuming that either `bcp` or `sqlcmd` can reliably output CSV: what happens if any of the field data contains CR/LF characters, quotes or commas? Consider using PowerShell's `Export-Csv` cmdlet or any other tool that can handle RFC 4180-style CSV data (i.e.: can quote and dequote delimited file data correctly).

Comment: Still working on this problem, but it seems like the problem stems from me not knowing how to handle VARCHARs containing a comma.